# Serializing a Scala Enum with Casbah

Tags: scala, casbah

How to serialize a Scala enum with Casbah ?

I have this error :

```
[info]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class scala.Enumeration$Val
[info]   at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:270)
[info]   at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:295)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context. Perhaps this question/answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019050/scala-serialization-exception-with-enumeration-value.

Comment: I've implented a workaround and posted it as an answer in the question that you've mentioned.

Comment: Glad to hear you are unblocked. Cheers.